# Android ExpandableListView OnChildClickListener Does not work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ExpandableListView and everything is ok. I have a checkbox in each child row that I want to toggle when I click on a child row as below:

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox.toggle();
        return true;
    }
});
```

The problem is that program never enters inside onChildClick() event handler. Any Idea?

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

set `android:focusable=false` for the **check box**. If it still doesn't work then add,

`android:descendantFocussability=blocksDescendants` to the top most layout.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to Enable

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28827162/1993847), you might have to add the following lines to your checkbox:

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

With this I could simply use the OnChildClickListener of the ExpandableListView